# predict() random forests - extract predictions from individual trees

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, caret

I built a random forest model called `iris_class` *.

```
set.seed(10)
index_row <- sample(2, 
                    nrow(iris), 
                    replace = T, 
                    prob = c(0.7, 0.3)
)  

train_data <- iris[index_row == 1,]
test_data <- iris[index_row == 2,]

iris_class <- randomForest(Species ~., 
                                data = train_data)
```

This is how `iris_class` looks like:

```
> iris_class

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = train_data) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.5%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         38          0         0  0.00000000
versicolor      0         39         2  0.04878049
virginica       0          3        29  0.09375000
```

I then use it to make predictions using the `predict()` function.

```
predictions<- predict(iris_class, test_data[,-5], type = "response")
```

`iris_class` is made of 500 individual trees. If I understand correctly, when I run `predict()` using `iris_class`, 500 trees are being generated, each gives a classification, and I am being shown the average result of those 500 trees.

My questions is:

**is there a way to extract the prediction of each of the 500 trees?**

In other words, can the `predict()` function return an object that, for each item being classified, will have 500 rows saying `setosa`, `versicolor` or `virginica`. Or a summarised version of such an object (shown below).  The purpose is: I want to know how "confident" the model actually is. When it predicts a plant to be `setosa`, is it 450 trees said `setosa` and 50 said something else, or is it 251 vs 249?

*What line of code will extract predictions for individual trees?*

My ideal output would look something like this:

```
> predictions_info
       setosa versicolor  virginica       pred
1  0.01517536 0.55449239 0.43033225 versicolor
2  0.21957988 0.71962024 0.06079987 versicolor
3  0.28146250 0.36777757 0.35075993 versicolor
4  0.51503150 0.41750308 0.06746543     setosa
5  0.25832598 0.10796878 0.63370523  virginica
6  0.24603616 0.07558151 0.67838233  virginica
7  0.02323489 0.41547464 0.56129047  virginica
8  0.41155830 0.49214444 0.09629726 versicolor
9  0.30217529 0.39852784 0.29929686 versicolor
10 0.45923782 0.49147493 0.04928725 versicolor
11 0.70479092 0.27648912 0.01871996     setosa
12 0.34489442 0.02606726 0.62903832  virginica
13 0.15553471 0.18903000 0.65543530  virginica
[...]
```

Where the `pred` column is what the `predict` function currently returns, and the first 3 columns show what proportion of the 500 trees gave which prediction. (These numbers and predictions are made up! and they don't match model output)

*This example is originally from this website (modified by me):
https://rpubs.com/Jay2548/519589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use predict.all = T. Then compute whatever you want with all the predictions. Be carefull, you will have a matrix of size : length(dataset) x number of trees